# Does the Schwarzschild metric solution require two (A and B, or g11 and g44) or four components (g11, g22, g33 and g44)?

Tags: gravity, general-relativity, theories, friedmann-equations

Different places on the web imply that Schwarzschild's metric uses four components or separate equations, similar to how Einstein's full set requires 6 or 10, or they say only two are needed.  Is it 2 or 4?

P.S.:  Why does Friedmann's first equation only need one?  What does Schwarzschild include that Friedmann doesn't?

Comment: Remember that Schwarzschild solutions involve just about every kind of symmetry there is, reducing the amount of equations needed considerably.

Comment: Does this help? https://hepweb.ucsd.edu/ph110b/110b_notes/node75.html